# SQL UPDATE Statement does not affect any rows (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I'am currently working on a project and want to make a simple page where I can edit groups. I had everything working fine in XAMPP and tried uploading it to the server, but it won't affect any rows in the database.This is the statement:

```
UPDATE user_groups 
SET name = 'TEST', 
name_short = 'test', 
color = 'green', 
category = 'MMORPG' 
WHERE id = 2
```

and:

```
Affected rows (UPDATE): 0
```

Is the answer. Creating new groups works fine (Local creating and editing works and I did not change anything in the statements since I uploaded both)

[This is what the row looks like that I am trying to affect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQv2a.jpg)

EDIT:

```
$sql_update_info = "UPDATE user_groups SET name = '$new_title', name_short = '$new_short', color = '$new_color', category = '$new_cat' WHERE id = $group_id";
$query_update_info = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_update_info);
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli));

echo '<br><span style="color:white;">'.$sql_update_info.'</span>';
```

Is what the PHP part looks like when clicked on the button.

Comment: Share the relevant PHP code, as query looks ok.

Comment: Do you have autocommit on?  Otherwise you have to commit.

Comment: On your localhost, you probably used MySQLi, but if you uploaded it on some server with different engine, it may not work as it did on your local machine. Try looking I to error log if something is there.

Comment: once try by executing the query in DB

Comment: Can you `echo $sql_update_info` and paste it here..

Comment: Also, you may want to close variables inside {} to prevent injection.

Comment: Tried executing it in the DB and it worked fine. @MilanChheda, The SQL statement shown above is the echo of $sql_update_info.

Comment: ´if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}´ returns "Transaction commit failed"

Comment: Have you tried printing db error  (`echo $mysqli->error`) ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Yes no connection error.

Comment: add error handler  `$query_update_info = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_update_info); if(!query_update_info){ echo mysqli_error($mysqli); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

**2nd :** `Execute()` will return true or false so based on that you need to handle the error like below.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user_groups SET name = ?, name_short = ?, color = ?, category = ? WHERE id = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $new_title, $new_short, $new_color, $new_cat, $group_id);

//The argument may be one of four types:

//i - integer
//d - double
//s - string
//b - BLOB
//change it by respectively 

$r = $stmt->execute();
if(!$r){  
    echo $stmt->error; 
}else{
   $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows; 
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```